# Windows 7 boot error 0xc0000225 after start of windows 10 upgrade

Tags: windows-7, boot

I recently tried to upgrade my Asus laptop to windows 10. At some point during the process, my computer restarted (I wasn't watching) and now it shows the error:

> /Boot/BCD
>
> 0xc0000225

I've looked around online and tried many different cmd things and nothing has worked.

I had windows 7 on C:\ and my data on D:\

When I use cmd on my windows 10 boot usb, my C:\ is shown (and I copied my important files to my external), but my D:\ is not.

```
bootrec /rebuildbcd
return 0 windows found
```

`bootrec /fixmbr` and `/fixboot` both return:

> the system cannot find the path specified

I would really like to at least get to my files on `D:\` and back them up on my external drive before formatting and reinstalling windows, but restoring my current setup would be best.

All help would be most appreciated. Thanks.

Added notes:

detail disk:

> ST9500420AS
> Disk ID:00000001
> Type:SATA
> Status:Online
> Path:0
> Target:0
> LUN ID:0
> Location Path:PCIROOT(0)#PCI(1F02)#ATA(C00T00L00)
> Current Read-only State:No
> Read-only:No
> Boot Disk:No
> Pagefile Disk:No
> Hibernation File Disk:No
> Crashdump Disk:No
> Clustered Disk:No
>
> Volume ###---Ltr---Label---Fs----Type------Size-----Status-----Info
> Volume 1------C-----OS----NTFS---Partition--465 GB---Healthy---

detail vol:

> Disk ###--Status---Size----Free---Dyn---Gpt
> Disk 0----Online---465 GB---0 B--- 
> Read-only:No
> Hidden:No
> No Default Drive Letter:No
> ShadowCopy:No
> Offline:No
> BitLockerEcrypted:No
> Installable:Yes
>
> Volume Capacity: 90 GB
> Volume Free Space: 8 GB

I find it weird that detail vol reports C: has having capacity of 90 GB and free space of 8 GB (which is what I expect it to be) while detail disk says it has 465 GB and 0 B free (implying that the other partition D: is still there but isn't seen by diskpart somehow)

UPDATED:

I've ran a BootMed bootable USB and ran TestDisk and it could not find either of my partitions.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 options

**A. This was already asked here**

**[Can I fix error 0xc0000225 without reinstalling Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/815267/can-i-fix-error-0xc0000225-without-reinstalling-windows)**

**B. If that fails it might sound weird to solve a WINDOWS issue using LINUX but i have done this many times get my/your files out.**

If you know your way around Linux you could just boot into the live CD, login, mount /dev/sda1 partition, plug your external media (usb drive/stick) mount that device and copy the files using command line.

If you don't know how to do opcion B then follow this steps and eventually get a dual boot (linux/windows) machine so if one fails you can still access your data from the other

**C. Install Linux Suse (for example) on C drive to access to D drive**

1. Get a Linux Live CD and burn it to a CD

https://software.opensuse.org/132/en

you can do this on a cafe-internet.

[image: This are you options for SUSE]
On the provided link you can download the whole DVD or download a CD network (the second option)

2. If you know your way around Linux you could just boot into the live CD, login, mount /dev/sda1 partition, plug your external media (usb drive/stick)
   mount that device and copy the files using command line. If not then continue to next step
3. Boot from the DVD/CD you burned and select "Installation" 
   (this will not format your drive will just launch the installation process

[image: select INSTALLATION option]

4. Read all the steps and STOP when you get to this window

**If you see any suggestion about FORMATING anything DO NOT click next**

[image]

**If you see any suggestion about FORMATING anything DO NOT click next**

5. select **CREATE CUSTOM PARTITION SETUP**
6. On the next window select **CUSTOM PARTITIONING -- FOR EXPERTS**

[image: select CUSTOM PARTITIONING]

7. Use the EDIT MOUNT OPTIONS for the partions that containg your data /dev/sda2 (2nd particion on the first Storage Device A) and mount your windows partition
8. Format your /dev/sda1 particion (C under windows) and create two partitions using the same sapce one for swap and another for ext3 installation for root (/) -- this a Linux requirement
9. Let the installation continue and boot into linux

Then you can use an external USB drive or stick, create a ZIP file or upload 
all that you need to the cloud.

---

if you get lost in my very abstract steps read this guide
https://activedoc.opensuse.org/book/opensuse-reference/chapter-1-installation-with-yast

**UPADTED** (if you dont see your partitions or dont match what you expected)

There might be two reasons

1. You have bad blocks in your hard disk and need to be tested (google that)
2. Or it seems that your partition table has been compromised. 
   So let your computer off and read follow this steps

   - https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/781778-how-to-fix-a-mangled-partition-table-on-linux
   - **http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=370121**
   - **http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/linux-data-recovery.html**

Avoid installing any other operational system and use a GPARTED LIVE CD

http://gparted.org/livecd.php

Once you have a GPARTED LIVE CD see this video

There is this youtube video about how to use the TestDisk (tool/command) 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vdoug-PI1bc

Gparted is a LINUX live cd that boots into a graphical environment with gparted launched automatically (used it to determine if what suse is showing you is real, but dont create any partitions or do any changes yet)

That video was taken from 
**https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/486227-how-to-recover-partition-table-using-gpart**

if none of that works then you can use PhotoRec to recover your files (but first make sure that you have done anything posible to restore the previous partition table)  (this tool will not always recover the original file names or folder structure so you can imagine !! –  Mauricio Gracia 3 mins ago

**http://cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec**

Comment: 1) the link you posted is something I've already read with no solution. 2) try use disk part to call "select partition 1" returns "There is no partition selected" and calling "active" returns the same. 3) I don't have a setup to use Linux and don't feel comfortable with trying to cut up my partition to do so. Isn't the a way to manually restore my BCD?

Comment: @DavyGamer and the rest of the steps ? do you need help to follow them ? if that is the case we can chat here or using whatsapp on your cell phone i can guide you

Comment: see my edited comment above.

Comment: @DavyGamer please read the following https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/300415 and provide the output `detail disk` command after you have selected one.

Comment: @DavyGamer also keep in mind that you can get your data out "If you know your way around Linux you could just boot into the live CD, login, mount /dev/sda1 partition, plug your external media (usb drive/stick) mount that device and copy the files using command line. " - then you can reinstall WINDOWS (my advice to you have a dual boot machine with Linux / Windows so if one fails you can work from the other)

Comment: detail disk:
ST9500420AS
Disk ID:00000001
Type:SATA
Status:Online
Path:0
Target:0
LUN ID:0
Location Path:PCIROOT(0)#PCI(1F02)#ATA(C00T00L00)
Current Read-only State:No
Read-only:No
Boot Disk:No
Pagefile Disk:No
Hibernation File Disk:No
Crashdump Disk:No
Clustered Disk:No
Volume ### Ltr  Label   Fs       Type         Size      Status     Info    
Volume 1     C    OS     NTFS   Partition  465 GB   Healthy

Comment: detail vol:
Disk ###  Status  Size       Free   Dyn  Gpt
Disk 0      Online  465 GB  0 B
Read-only:No
Hidden:No
No Default Drive Letter:No
ShadowCopy:No
Offline:No
BitLockerEcrypted:No
Installable:Yes
Volume Capacity: 90 GB
Volume Free Space: 8 GB

Comment: I find it weird that detail vol report C: has having capacity of 90 GB and free space of 8 GB (which is what I expect it to be) while detail disk says it has 465 GB and 0 B free (implying that the other partition D: is still there but isn't seen by diskpart somehow)

Comment: @DavyGamer please include this in a formated way in your question

Comment: @Mauricio_Gracia see edited post above.

Comment: @DavyGamer what about all this comments with "DETAIL DISK" ? en anything else that you think is relevant should be on the question itself

Comment: Please see "detail disk" output above. Does it provide additional info to help solve the issue? Note: I'm unable to burn a Linux disc because I have no other available computer.

Comment: @DavyGamer visit and internet place and burn a linux network cd or even burn a GPARTED RESCUE SYSTEM, please use google to search for USE LINUX TO RESCUE YOUR SYSTEM/DATA

Comment: I got openSuse on a bootable USB and got thru step 6 of your guide but now I'm stuck. It appears I'm on a newer version than you have shown and I don't see the Edit Mount Options anywhere. Plus, it currently only shows /dev/sda a a single Unpartioned drive. What should I do?

Comment: @DavyGamer see the UPDATED section of my answer and could you offer a bounty on this question so that other people can provide other answers or comments on this one. Thanks

Comment: 1) what do you mean "offer a bounty"? What is that and is there something special I would need to do to set that up? 2) I tried Testdisk and it returned no results.

Comment: 1) below your question there is an option that says "start a bounty". Use it to offer points to draw attention to this questions. 2) It seems that we need to find other tools, I will your email later.