# VHD boot error 0xc0000225

Tags: boot, windows-8, windows-server-2012-r2, vhd, boot-to-vhd

I am converting a physical Windows Server 2012 R2 to a VM which will be hosted on Hyper-V core server.

Steps I have followed:

1. Created a VHD from existing Windows 2012 R2 **physical disk** using [Starwind](https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-v2v-converter)
2. Installed Hyper-V 2019 core
3. Copied the VHD file to the the Hyper-V machine
4. Created a new VM, using the VHD created in step 1

When attempting to boot, an error is thrown:

```
 Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.
 The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible.
```

[image]

Now the VHD content seems to be fine. When manually mounted it will show 3 partitions (Disk 1 in the image below):

[image]

Within the VM, I can optionally boot the Windows setup disk and enter repair mode, and access the faulty VHD partitions...

So the question is, what partition should I make bootable and how?

Similar [to this](https://superuser.com/questions/815267/can-i-fix-error-0xc0000225-without-reinstalling-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed following [this article](https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/windows-8-mbr-fix.html).....

> 1. Boot from the original installation DVD.
> 2. At the Welcome screen, click Repair your computer.
> 3. Choose "Troubleshoot > Advanced options > Command Prompt".
>    process of command prompt
> 4. When the Command Prompt loads, type the following commands in order:
>
>    bootrec /FixMbr
>
>    bootrec /FixBoot
>
>    bootrec /ScanOs
>
>    bootrec /RebuildBcd
>
> Remember to press "Enter" after each command and wait for each operation to finish.
>
> 5. Remove the DVD from the disk tray.
> 6. Type exit and Hit "Enter".
> 7. Restart your computer and check if Windows 8/8.1 can boot now.